# How to show the index of the current match?

Tags: search

I search some words so that there are many highlight results in the current window.

I use `n` to move cursor to a matching result, how to know its index of match results easily？

I have tried [SearchPosition](https://github.com/vim-scripts/SearchPosition), but it does not work in my Vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's exactly what you want, but to get the number of matches and the index of the current match, I'm using a modified version of this:

```
nno n n@=Search_and_index()<CR>
nno N N@=Search_and_index()<CR>

fu! Search_and_index() abort
    let winview     = winsaveview()
    let [line, col] = [winview.lnum, winview.col]

    call cursor(1, 1)
    let [idx, total]          = [1, 0]
    let [matchline, matchcol] = searchpos(@/, 'cW')
    while matchline && total <= 999
        let total += 1
        if matchline < line || (matchline == line && matchcol <= col)
            let idx += 1
        endif
        let [matchline, matchcol] = searchpos(@/, 'W')
    endwhile

    call winrestview(winview)
    echo @/ . '(' . idx . '/' . total . ')'
    return ''
endfu
```

---

It remaps `n` and `N` to call the function `Search_and_index()` which should echo a message such as `pattern(3/4)`.

The while loop is responsible for incrementing the variables `total` and `idx`. And at the end of the loop, their values should be respectively the total number of matches of your last search pattern, and the index of the current match (the one under the cursor).

But the loop stops at `999` to avoid taking too much time. You could increase this number if you feel it's too low.

Comment: My English is poor, but you are right, I want to get the index of the current match! By the way the number of matches is useful too, thank you!